# Keras not converging to optimum while TensorFlow does

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, keras, reinforcement-learning, q-learning

I'm working on a Reinforcement learning project where the agent needs to navigate itself around the maze and get to the goal. (I used Q Learning as my algorithm) The agent found the optimal path in 50 episodes when using TensorFlow, and consistently obtained the optimum reward. The graph's something like this:
[TensorFlow Version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yLxq0.png)

Since I wanted to use Keras for fast prototyping in the future, I tried coding the exact same algorithm with Keras. However, even though I'm using the same optimization functions(cost functions are slightly different), the AI written on Keras fluctuates a lot. Something like this:
[Keras Version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5qyxY.png)

My backend is TensorFlow, and I tried switching to Theano, but no luck.

My TensorFlow code:

```
import numpy as np
import random
import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

tf.reset_default_graph()

def action(env, s, a):
    env[s] = "_"
    c = True
    if a == 1 and s >= 5:
        s1 = s-5
    elif a == 3 and s <= 19:
        s1 = s+5
    elif a == 2 and s%5 != 4:
        s1 = s+1
    elif a == 4 and s%5 != 0 and s > 0:
        s1 = s-1
    else:
        s1 = s
        r = -1
        d = False
    if env[s1] == "0":
        r = -5
        d = False
        c = False
    elif env[s1] == "G":
        r = 100
        d = True
        c = False
    else:
        r = -1
        d = False
    return s1, r, d, c

def reset_env():
#The maze
    default_env = ["_"] * 25
    default_env[0] = "A"
    default_env[1] = "0"
    default_env[7] = "0"
    default_env[8] = "0"
    default_env[11] = "0"
    default_env[24] = "G"
    return default_env

inputs1 = tf.placeholder(shape=[1,25],dtype=tf.float32)
W = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([25,4],0,0.01))
Qout = tf.matmul(inputs1,W)
predict = tf.argmax(Qout,1)

nextQ = tf.placeholder(shape=[1,4],dtype=tf.float32)
loss = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(nextQ - Qout))
trainer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=0.1)
updateModel = trainer.minimize(loss)

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

y = 0.5
e = 0
num_episodes = 500

rList = []
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)
    success = 0
    for i in range(num_episodes):
        rAll = 0
        s = 0
        d = False
        env = reset_env()
        j = 0
        c = True
        print "------------------START-------------------"
        while j < 100:
            j += 1
            a,allQ = sess.run([predict,Qout],feed_dict=    {inputs1:np.identity(25)[s:s+1]})
            if np.random.rand(1) < e:
                a[0] = random.randint(0,3)
            s1,r,d,c = action(env, s, int(a[0]+1))
            #print s1, r, d, c
            env[s1] = "A"
            Q1 = sess.run(Qout,feed_dict={inputs1:np.identity(25)[s1:s1+1]})
            maxQ1 = np.max(Q1)
            targetQ = allQ
            targetQ[0,a[0]] = r + y*maxQ1
            _,W1 = sess.run([updateModel,W],feed_dict={inputs1:np.identity(25)[s:s+1],nextQ:targetQ})
            rAll += r
            s = s1
            if c == False:
                break
            if d == True:
                e = 1./((i/50) + 10)
                success += 1
                break
        rList.append(rAll)
plt.plot(rList)
plt.show()
```

My Keras code:

```
import numpy as np
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras import optimizers
import numpy

def action(env, s, a):
    env[s] = "_"
    c = True
    if a == 1 and s >= 5:
        s1 = s-5
    elif a == 3 and s <= 19:
        s1 = s+5
    elif a == 2 and s%5 != 4:
        s1 = s+1
    elif a == 4 and s%5 != 0 and s > 0:
        s1 = s-1
    else:
        s1 = s
        r = -1
    if env[s1] == "0":
        r = -10
        d = False
        c = False
    elif env[s1] == "G":
        r = 100
        d = True
        c = False
    else:
        r = -1
        d = False
    return s1, r, d, c

def reset_env():
    default_env = ["_"] * 25
    default_env[0] = "A"
    default_env[1] = "0"
    default_env[7] = "0"
    default_env[8] = "0"
    default_env[11] = "0"
    default_env[24] = "G"
    return default_env

sgd = optimizers.SGD(lr=0.1)
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(4, input_dim=25, kernel_initializer='uniform'))
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error',
          optimizer=sgd,
          metrics=['accuracy'])
y = 0.5
e = 0
num_episodes = 100

rList = []
success = 0
for i in range(num_episodes):
    rAll = 0
    s = 0
    d = False
    env = reset_env()
    j = 0
    c = True
    print "---------------START-------------------"
    while j < 100:
        j += 1
        allQ = model.predict(np.identity(25)[s:s+1])[0]
        a = allQ.argmax()
        if np.random.rand(1) < e:
           a = random.randint(0,3)
        s1,r,d,c = action(env, s, int(a+1))
        env[s1] = "A"
        Q1 = model.predict(np.identity(25)[s1:s1+1])[0]
        maxQ1 = np.max(Q1)
        targetQ = allQ
        targetQ[a] = r + y*maxQ1
        model.fit(np.identity(25)[s:s+1], np.array([targetQ]), epochs=1, verbose=0)
        rAll += r
        s = s1
        if c == False:
            break
        if d == True:
            e = 1./((i/50) + 10)
            success += 1
            break
    rList.append(rAll)
plt.plot(rList)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Keras with TF as backend has known issues with reproducibility. What backend are you using?  If you try with Theano, do you get reproducible results?

Comment: @Hobbes  Sorry, I forgot to mention that. Yes, I'm currently using Tensorflow. I'll try using Theano now; I'll report back shortly.

Comment: @Hobbes Sadly, that didn't work out. The output graph is still very unstable.

Comment: In you Keras implementation you are not using you own SGD but the default one which uses a different learning rate. When I change `optimizer='sgd'` to  `optimizer=sgd` I get a stable result, but always converging to -100. Not sure if this is correct.

Comment: @AndréBergner Sadly, no. As you can see the graph when you run my TF code, it's supposed to converge to 93. Thanks though!

Comment: What is the purpose of defining sgd but not using it. As @AndréBergner said, I think you should be using you're defined sgd.

Comment: The instability you are seeing is most likely caused by your learning rate. In which case you need to set the learning rate yourself if you do not want to use the default one.

Comment: @JahKnows Right, after André mentioned it I've fixed and tried it, but still no avail... I'll update my code so nobody gets confused, sorry.